# Passing Data to Second View in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to pass data (incomeAmount) from the First View to the Second View in my SwiftUI app, but I need to declare the BindingString. What does it mean that I need to declare the BindingString?

View 1

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var incomeAmount = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
                VStack {
                    TextField("Your income amount", text: $incomeAmount)
                        .frame(width: 300)
                        .padding(.bottom, 30)
                    
                    
                    NavigationLink(destination: NewView()){
                            
                            Text("Continue")
                                .frame(width: 300, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                                .background(Color.black)
                                .cornerRadius(130)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .padding(.bottom, 30)
                        }
                    
                    Text("$\(incomeAmount)")
                        
                    
                }.navigationTitle("First View")
            }
        }
    }
```

View 2

```
struct NewView: View {
    @Binding var incomeAmount: String
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("$\(incomeAmount)")
            }
        }.navigationTitle("Second View")
    }
}

struct NewView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NewView(incomeAmount: <#Binding<String>#>)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass the incomeAmount to the second view, you have to do this:

```
NavigationLink(destination: NewView(incomeAmount: $incomeAmount)) { ... }
```

Also, you need to provide it to:

```
struct NewView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    NewView(incomeAmount: .constant("something here"))
}
}
```

Because in PreviewProvider, NewView expect to have a Binding<String> passed in. So you need to provide it.

Comment: You absolute god - I know it's simple, but I was struggling for 3 hours! Thank you very much :)